# Распарсить формулы

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите пожалуйста распарсить формулы из textbox.

Почему вот так не работает:

```
ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser();
parser.Values.Add("x", x);
parser.Values.Add("y", y);

y_[0] = 1;
y_[1] = parser.Parse(string.Format("{0}", dx_dt.Text));
y_[2] = parser.Parse(string.Format("{0}", dy_dt.Text));
```

А вот так работает:

```
ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser();
parser.Values.Add("x", x);
parser.Values.Add("y", y);

y_[0] = 1;
y_[1] = parser.Parse("y+2");
y_[2] = parser.Parse("x+y");
```

Добавил код:

```
public void five(double[] y4, out double[] y_)
{
    ....

    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser();

    parser.Values.Add("x", x);
    parser.Values.Add("y", y);

    y_[0] = 1;
    y_[1] = parser.Parse(dx_dt.Text);
    y_[2] = parser.Parse(dy_dt.Text);

    parser.Values.Clear();
}// five

static public void RungeKutteZick(float h, double[] yy_, out double[] y1)
{
    .......

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < SizeSys; m++)
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == 3)
                {
                    yy[m] = yy_[m] + yy[m];
                }
                else
                {
                    yy[m] = yy_[m] + yy[m] * 0.5f;
                }
            }

            dy = five(yy);
```

Comment: А зачем здесь `string.Format`? Судя по коду, он не делает ровным счётом ничего, что получил, то и отдает.

Comment: Я в принципе согласен, если запускать первый вариант выходит такая ошибка "First argument to method Parse is null or empty"

Comment: Значит на момент запуска кода, в вашем текстбоксе ничего нет. Где размещён код и как он запускается?

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: С помощью кнопки передаются значения и запускается цикл

Comment: Форма создает саму себя и вызывает в ней какой-то метод? Я еще больше запутался. И почему вы используете `out` вместо возвращаетого значения? Вы же в курсе, что `void` можно заменить на нужный тип, а потом сделать `return y_;`?

Comment: В принципе от этого ничего не меняется, вопрос в том, как должны оказаться введенные формулы в заданных textbox

Comment: Вы зря убрали код, к которому относится часть моего ответа. Ответ становится основанным на неизвестном коде, который я непонятно откуда взял. Верните в вопрос хотя-бы ключевую часть кода, содержащую ошибку. StackOverflow читают и другие, не знакомые нам люди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сперва ошибки. Не нужно использовать `out` там где один возвращаемый тип, а не 2 и более.

```csharp
public void five(double[] y4, out double[] y_)
```

замените на

```csharp
public double[] five(double[] y4)
```

А это

```csharp
y_ = new double[3];
```

на это

```csharp
double[] y_ = new double[3];
```

Затем уберите это, оно бесполезно, так как парсер по завершении работы метода уничтожится сам

```csharp
parser.Values.Clear();
```

И на это же место добавьте

```csharp
return y_;
```

Затем в вызывающем методе замените

```csharp
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.five(yy, out dy);
```

На

```csharp
dy = five(yy);
```

Потому что вы не используете в методе текстбоксы текущей формы, а создаете новую, в которой они не инициализированы (там `null`), потому что вы вызываете метод до того, как в текстбоксах что-то появится. И мне кажется, здесь вообще вам не нужно создавать копию текущей формы. А если я ошибаюсь и так задумано, напишите мне об этом в комментарии к этому ответу.

И уберите `static` у вызывающего метода.

Comment: `five` вызывается в статическом методе (не знаю чего)

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: static убрать везде

Comment: @Igor точняк, не заметил :)